# cookies are not getting shared with subdomain in .net6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have migrated my **.NET core3.0 code to .NET 6**.
After migration, cookies are not getting shared from mydomain.com to localhost.mydomain.com **allowed domain**.
Below is my code to create the cookies.

```
var setCookieHeaderValue = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.SetCookieHeaderValue("cookiename", "test")
                {
                    Domain = ".mydomain.com",
                    Path = "/",
                    Secure = true,
                    HttpOnly = true
                    
                };

                context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.SetCookie] = Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues.Concat(context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.SetCookie], setCookieHeaderValue.ToString());
```

***same code is working in vs2019***.
I tried changing the samesite,secure and httponly properties, but no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.
[image: cookie image]

***Steps to Reproduce***
1.copy the above code in asp.net core web app with vs20222, run it with  chrome,you will find the cookie(run with the domain with localhost.mydomain.com).
2.create another asp.net core webapp in VS2022 and paste the below code to read the cookie
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookiename"] ,run it with same domain localhost.mydomain.com , you will get the new window opened.
this new window will show no cookie.

Comment: Is the snippet code you provided written in the controller?

Comment: this code is written in middleware class file

Comment: Do you mind share the details about your middleware? It will easy for us to reproduce the issue in our side. As you know, the behavior in .net3.0 &6.0 should be same. So we need your minimal reproducible problem snippet. Pls hide your sensitive info.

Comment: we are not setting same site value here, do you think it can be due to this.in browser it is showing samesite to none

Comment: Have you tried to use [the official sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#share-cookies-across-subdomains) to test it, I mean you can disable your custom middleware and test it. If the behaviors are different, it means your code in middleware has some issue when used in .net6.